# Make and reflect changes to popup.html in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extensions. I am trying to make a basic extension which updates the value to an input field in the popup page every few seconds. Here is my current code.

manifest.json

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Test extension",
 "version": "1",
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "tl.png",
    "default_popup": "layout.html"
 },
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js","addvalues.js"],
    "persistent": false
 },

 "permissions": [
        "alarms",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation"
   ]

}
```

layout.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="addvalues.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="pfvalue"> Portfolio value </label>
    <input id="pfvalue" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 10px;">

</body>
</html>
```

addvalues.js

```
$(function()
{
    var i=0;
    var portvalue;
    function getData()
    {    
        portvalue = i;                       
        $("#pfvalue").val(portvalue);
        i++;
        console.log(portvalue);
    }    

    getData();   
    chrome.alarms.create("fetch data",{periodInMinutes: 0.1});
    chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(getData);        
});
```

When I keep the popup page open for long enough, the input value does change like it is supposed to. But when I close it and then open it again, the popup page resets to the initial state of showing 0. I am not able to figure out why this happens.

The console shows the right value of portvalue (i.e. the one that gets updated every 6 seconds).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure to read the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): the popup is a separate page that exists only while shown. To view its devtools and console rightclick the popup and click Inspect.
2. A background/event page is a separate, hidden page with its own DOM so no need to load jQuery there.
3. Your background page can increment the value and store it via `chrome.storage.local.set`
4. Your popup.js (a different script) can use `chrome.storage.local.get` on startup and `chrome.storage.onChanged` to detect the changes
5. It's meaningless to use an event page (`"persistent" : false` in your manifest.json) if you wake it up every 6 seconds because an event page is unloaded automatically after 5 seconds since its last activation, meaning your event page currently gets unloaded every 6 seconds for just 1 second. That's a waste of the computer resources: every time it loads the browser needs to parse it, compile it, optimize it and so on.

Comment: can you please tell me how to interact with multiple scripts file and their html pages?

Comment: @AshuMhatugade, doesn't seem related to this topic. Please ask a new question.